# Where can I find the Xml Documentation files for the .NET 4.0 or 4.5 framework?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, xml-documentation

for .NET 2.0, the xml documentation files for the framework assemblies where located at this position:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\en
```

I can't find a corresponding folder for .NET 3.5, 4 or even 4.5.

So, where, by default, are the xml documentation files for the framework assemblies located for newer .NET framework versions?

I'm especially interested in System.Web.dll documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
```